# When to use past tense after reported speech and when to use present tense after it?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense, reported-speech

1. He said that he **had visited** Paris last year.
2. She said that she **is** currently working on a new project.

Comment: Presumably her work is ongoing now. That's the inference a listener might draw.  That sentence might be spoken by someone who is relaying the contents of a *recent* conversation.

Comment: Your title asks about using tenses "after" reported speech, but your questions use those tenses in it. Also, you should cite the sources of quoted text (or tell us if you made up those examples yourself). Also, you should indicate what research you've done on this issue (for example, do you know what the "past perfect" is and how it's used?).